# Streamlining insertion of relational data into database using Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm currently using Flask and looking upload a large amount of articles (50 million total), each of which is written by a varying number of users (~100 million total). To do this, I have created an Article model, a User model, and a Contribution model which links users to articles in a many-to-many relationship.

My current uploading process is as follows:

```
article_dictionary = create_article_dictionary()
user_dictionary = create_user_dictionary()

for xml_file in files:
    with gzip.GzipFile(xml_file,'rb') as gfile:
        root = open_as_xml_tree(gfile)  
        for article in root:            
            # parse XML file using custom XML_Article class
            article_object = XML_Article(xml_article=article)
            # create Article object
            new_article = Article(  title = article_object.article_title,
                                    pubdate = article_object.publication_date,
                                    article_id = article_object.article_id
                                )
            if not article_dictionary.get(new_article.article_id):
                # update the dict keeping track of which articles are indexed
                article_dictionary[new_article.article_id]=1
                db.session.add(new_article)
                db.session.flush()

                # add each author in the article
                for author in article_object.authors:
                    new_user = User(firstname=author.firstname,midname=author.midname,lastname=author.lastname)
                    # if the user does exist, don't add them, just note their contribution
                    if user_dictionary.get(new_user.firstname + new_user.midname + new_user.lastname):
                        new_contribution = Contributions(   user_id = user_full_name[new_user.firstname + new_user.midname + new_user.lastname],
                                                            article_id = new_article.article_id,
                                                            # other information about the contribution is here
                                                        )
                    # if they don't, add them
                    else:
                        db.session.add(new_user)
                        db.session.flush()
                        new_contribution = Contributions(   user_id = new_user.user_id,
                                                            article_id = new_article.article_id,
                                                            # other information about the contribution is here
                                                        )                       
                        user_dictionary[new_user.firstname + new_user.midname + new_user.lastname]=new_user.user_id
                    db.session.add(new_contribution)
                    db.session.flush()
                    count+=1
        db.session.commit()
```

However, this is very slow and not enough for 50 million entries. I suspect the slow speed is in part due to having to repeatedly add and flush and I wonder if there is any way to do this in bulk that would be much quicker.

Comment: If you google around there are a lot of articles about how to speed up insert speeds in SQLite. It does take some tweaking, in particular choosing the right PRAGMAs. See: http://blog.quibb.org/2010/08/fast-bulk-inserts-into-sqlite/ for a start. And maybe https://medium.com/@JasonWyatt/squeezing-performance-from-sqlite-insertions-971aff98eef2

Comment: ["ORMs are basically not intended for high-performance bulk inserts"](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/faq/performance.html#i-m-inserting-400-000-rows-with-the-orm-and-it-s-really-slow)